# ASP.NET MVC: View gets rendered in an alert window

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

My view gets rendered in an alert window.  I have a post action that adds a new record to my repository, and then returns a list of matching objects for display:

```
    [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Add(FormCollection collection)
            {
    ...
    _repository.AddMyObject(myobject);
    _repository.Save()
    _matchingResults = _repository.GetMatchingResults(myobject);

    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        return View("Results", _matchingResults );
    ...
}
```

"Results" is a view that renders a list of matchingResults.  However, all I get is an alert window with the rendered html.  I can't use RedirectToAction because I need to pass in _matchingResults.

Any suggestions?

Comment: show us your client-side code.

Answer (score 1):

Your view rendering the results should be a partial view i.e. Results.ascx (user control) and then you would return that to the view via `return PartialView("Results", _matchingResults)`

Answer (score 0):

One work around although ugly might be to use Tempdata to store what you want and retrieve it in your `Results` action as TempData persists between two requests

However TempData can only store strings but Phil Haacked comes to a rescue with this [blog](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/12/21/asp.net-mvc-helpers-for-repopulating-a-form.aspx).

> A common pattern when submitting a
>   form in ASP.NET MVC is to post the
>   form data to an action which performs
>   some operation and then redirects to
>   another action afterwards. The only
>   problem is, the form data is not
>   repopulated automatically after a
>   redirect. Let's look at remedying
>   that, shall we?